# Is putting logic in SQLprocedures/functions (as opposed to PHP/Perl) acceptable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I'm doing a **university-related** database project in which I am asked to design a database (the specifications **explicitly** ask me to throw in at least a few SQL procedures and triggers in it) and stick a little web interface on top of it.

If it matters, I'm modeling a car rental and I'm using MySQL and PHP.

It is very important to note that the whole point of the project is most definitely the database.
**It's a database project**, period.

Now, I am wondering: should I put as much logic as possible in SQL procedures/functions or not?
Since it's very much a *database* project and I'm already putting some logic in it because of the requirements, my answer would tend to be "yes", also because it would be very good for **decoupling** (very hypotetically, if some guy decides to write e.g. a desktop or Android frontend to it, there would be much less chance of having different behaviours between client applications, so it sounds like good design to me).

But what's holding me is that I've **never seen anybody doing that IRL**, I've always seen people writing the logic in C/PHP, so I wonder: **is using SQL procedures for business logic acceptable**?
Is it good practice?

*As an example: should I have a SQL procedure called RENT_OUT_CAR or a PHP function called rentOutCar(...) for the purpouse of, well, renting out a car, aka marking its status as "rented", adding a timestamp, removing its association with the garage it was parked in, etc?
Or consider COMPUTE_TOTAL_COST vs computeTotalCost(), which computes the final price charged to the customer.*

Thank you all!

P.S.: **ORMs and fancy stuff is explicitly not allowed**, I *have* to stick to **plain PHP.**

P.P.S.: This question looks suspiciously similar, but I think I am operating under very different constraints: [Pros and cons of putting logic in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309683/pros-and-cons-of-putting-logic-in-sql)

Comment: Either you've misunderstood something or the requirements are nonsense. MySQL supports stored routines (functions, procedures, triggers, ...) and many projects are using them. [PL/SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) is not supported by MySQL, so you can't use it in your project.

Comment: Sorry, I confused PL/SQL with stored routines and procedures. Edited accordingly.

Comment: (The lecturer's slides do seem to use either interchangeably, though)

Comment: What about your constraints makes you think those answers don't apply? (Don't interpret the answers only in light of that question's particular technique; understand the reasoning for encapsulating in the DBMS.) You might want to post on dba.stackexchange: you'll find much less tolerance for extra-database code. ORMs arise from mistunderstanding relational principles.

Comment: @philipxy: I guess those answers are somewhat applicable, but the OP in that question seems to operate under different requirements - I think my situation is slightly different in that the circumstances do significantly weigh in favor of doing things in the database - hope I am getting myself explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what's holding me is that I've never seen anybody doing that IRL,
>   I've always seen people writing the logic in C/PHP, so I wonder: is
>   using SQL procedures for business logic acceptable? Is it good
>   practice?

Anything that should apply to all clients, regardless of the language, is a prospect for the database. *All clients* includes the command-line and GUI interfaces that ship with your dbms.

The last Fortune 100 database I worked on had hundreds of applications written in at least two dozen languages accessing it. I think the oldest applications were first released to production in the 1970s.

Comment: I like the rationale here, that's what I'm thinking as well.

(Of course there won't /actually/ be other clients in practice and in fact the database will never be in production.)

Answer (score 0):

As so often: Yes, put logic into the database! But dont abuse it ;-)

Like in MVC; all the bekongs to "M" is good to put into the Database if you want (its not a must) and if your ORM (or not used ORM) allows it.

ORMs - I would say the tools arround - often 'dont like things in the database' like procedures because they cant handle it. Store procedures and its friends are powerfull tools, to gether performance especially if the Controller and Model (ie the Database) are on different servers probabliy ver long distance between. then the RTT can get a real problem, when you have manny single selects, to get a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If the project that you are given is a "database project", then it's acceptable to have all the logic in the database. As said in the comments MySQL supports stored routines (functions, procedures, triggers) and you can put your logic there.

As for your question whether you should have a "SQL procedure called RENT_OUT_CAR or a PHP function called rentOutCar(...)" - you should have both. The PHP function should only do a query to call the stored procedure/function with the needed params(if any) and return the results of it. That way the project can be easily migrated to another language that can use the database. I.e. if you need to rewrite the project in Perl/Java/etc., you would only have to rewrite the functions that call the stored routines and show the results.

Furthermore the database could be accessed from another source(your PHP project rewritten in another language or a totally different one), retaining all the business logic.

Comment: Re: the "you should have both. [...] and return the results of it." - bit. 


Makes lots of sense, thanks.